# Sitecore term query for filter data

Tags: lucene, sitecore

In Sitecore lucene search i am using "term query" to filter data from sitecore. 
Here i have one field in Sitecore called "Description" and i want to do fileration based on term "Lorem". But every time I am getting 0 result. If i dont use rterm query i get all result that means my index configuration is correct. Please help.

```csharp
TermQuery bothQuery = new TermQuery (new Term("Description", "Lorem"));
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.Add(bothQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
TopDocs topDocs = sc.Searcher.Search(query, int.MaxValue);
SearchHits searchHits = new SearchHits(topDocs, sc.Searcher.GetIndexReader());
return searchHits.FetchResults(0, int.MaxValue).Select(r => r.GetObject<Item>()).ToList();
```

Comment: Is the description field tokenized?

Comment: You need to modify your index configuration. Martin is right, the field does need to be tokenized for your query to work. Also keep in mind, TermQuery is case-sensitive. If you post some more information on how you are configuring your index, we might be able to give you more of an answer.

Comment: Hi Mark , I am posting my configue setting . Please let me know it its correct

Answer (score 0):

I note that your Term definition above has a field name containing a capital letter. You don't specify the version of Sitecore / Lucene you're working in, but my experience with the 6.x series of Sitecore is that the indexing process transforms all the Field names to lower case at index time.

Hence your field in Sitecore might be called "Description" but in Lucene's index it is probably called "description". Try changing your code to use a lower case field name.

You can check this using an index display tool like the [Lucene Index Viewer from the Sitecore Marketplace](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Index_Viewer.aspx). It will show you the names of the fields in your index, and let you test queries against them without the need to recompile code.